# JProfiler with Netbeans Platform application

Tags: netbeans-platform, jprofiler

I have integrated `JProfiler` in to **Netbeans IDE (8.2)** and tried profiling a normal Java Project and the profiler started without any problem.

However, if i try to profile a **Netbeans Platform application (RCP)** it throws the following error,

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of JProfiler 10.1, Netbeans RCP applications are not supported by the JProfiler Netbeans plugin. You have to invoke

Session->Integration wizards->Remote Integration Wizard

in JProfiler and add the -agentpath VM parameter that is provided by the wizard to your launch configuration in Netbeans. Then you can start the application in Netbeans with the "Run" action and connect with the JProfiler session that is created by the wizard.